# In ReactJS, how do you pass a collection to children elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React app, I set a state object in the constructor of Main.jsx:

```
this.state = { code: [['Z','R','W','O'],['R','C'],['J'],['N','S','J','T','O','X','K']]}
```

I can then pass that object to a child object as the props:

`<CodeArea code={this.state.code}/>`

In my CodeArea component, I want to create a collection of words, one for each sub-array of the code, and pass it to the CodeWords component.

CodeArea.jsx:

```
import CodeWords from "./CodeWords"

export default class CodeArea extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let words = this.props.code.map((word, index) => <CodeWords key={index} {...word} />)
    return(
      <div className="collection">
        {words}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

`this.props.code` is the correct code, and is mapped to a collection of CodeWords.

CodeWords.jsx:

```
import CodeLetter from "./CodeLetter"

export default class CodeWords extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let word = this.props.words.map((letter, index) => <CodeLetter key={index} {...letter} />)
    return (
      <table>
        {word}
      </table>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error in CodeWords:

```
CodeWords.jsx:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
at CodeWords.render (CodeWords.jsx:5)
```

**How do I reference the {words} collection from CodeArea in CodeWords?** I eventually want to take each of the {words} elements, which should be CodeWords components, and split them into CodeLetter components.

Comment: this.props.words will be undefined since in codeArea.jsx using spread with word won't work. Try with { ...props} which will send the entire props to codewords ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are spreading `...` `word` onto the `CodeWords` component, you are effectively creating the component like this ([react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes)):

```
<CodeWords key={index} Z='Z' R='R' W='W' O='O' />
```

What you want to do in `CodeArea` is send the `codeWord` (entire array of letters) to the `CodeWords` component:

```
let words = this.props.code.map((codeWord, index) => <CodeWords key={index} words={codeWord} />)
```

This will give you a `this.props.words` in your `CodeWords` component.

I also think you would benefit from renaming a few things:

- your `CodeWords` component can be `CodeWord` (singular) since it seems to me that you intend it to only represent a single group of letters.
- the `let words` variable could be `let codeWords`
- in `CodeWords` the `let word` should probably be `let letters`

Comment: This is very helpful.  Thanks - I'm now on to different errors!